# Can't install mysql server version 8 on Ubuntu 18.04, error libpthread.so.0 not found. How to solve?

Tags: mysql

I'm having the following problem:

-I add the mysql official repository

-Install the mysql-server package, version 8

-Error makes it impossible for the install to end. The error says that there is no libpthread.so.0 with a "no such file or directory" error.

I've been googling the answer for hours, and finally decided to come here.... but because I managed to resolve it by reading a similar problem with mysql-server vesion 5.7, but with libaio.1 file, so see the answer for my case below, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case the problem was not the libpthread.so.0 file; it was present (in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`). The actual problem was Apparmor, which I didn't know about. It's a service that acts like an inner firewall of sorts; instead of blocking net connections, it blocks apps from doing things in the system (or that's my impression)... the error doesn't say anything about apparmor; that's why it's harder to track down.

### Solution steps

Purge out (or remove if you want to keep databases) any MySQL packages to repeat the installation anew:

```
sudo apt purge "mysql*"
```

Autoremove packages

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Stop the apparmor service

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
```

Make apparmor drop its profiles (I thought with stop it was enough, but for me it wasn't. With `systemctl` it doesn't work)

```
sudo service apparmor teardown
```

Reinstall mysql-server

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Install apparmor-utils, to create a profile for MySQL in apparmor that allows MySQL to run

```
sudo apt install apparmor-utils
```

Check the status of mysql-server (must be Active(running))

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

Generate a profile for MySQL in apparmor

```
sudo aa-genprof mysql
```

In another terminal run MySQL (enter root password)

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Do things in MySQL while apparmor is generating the profile in the other terminal

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE fooDB
```

Swith to the other terminal and press <kbd>s</kbd> (the prompt tells you it's for "scan")

Say yes to the policies from apparmor as you see fit (I guess all of them for mysql), say yes pressing "a" for Allow

Press <kbd>f</kbd> to Finish the apparmor profile

Restart the apparmor service

```
sudo systemctl start apparmor
```

Check to see if you still can use MySQL in the other terminal

```
mysql>exit
mysql -u root -p
```

If all is well you can use MySQL from the command line.